# Node express app with socket.io not working after deploy on heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, websocket, socket.io

Hello I'm trying to deploy an **express app that uses Socket.io** for communication with the **node server** it's hosted on.

First problem : the server couldn't find the socket.io node module
    somehow... even though it gets resolved on localhost.

We then switched to loading the socket.io client side through the socket.io cdn.
    But we are getting this being spammed in the console :

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)
>   https://pictionar-e.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Lbg7iEM

From this error is looks like socket.io is trying to communicate over polling ? But I don't get why.. heroku supports websockets. Could https cause things not to work anymore?

Server side we've got the socketio/express server setup like this :

```
app=express();
server=require("http").Server(app);
server.listen(port,function () {
    console.log("Server started at port: "+port);
});
io=require("socket.io")(server);
```

On localhost everything works fine but when on heroku the socket.io doesn't work, while the express server does its thing perfectly fine...

*Note: we are using the port that gets assigned automatically by the heroku environment*